# Android refresh TextViews in all fragments from mainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

can't understand how to refresh/update all my textviews. They are located in 13 different fragments and I can't acces them how I want.

In simple Java I got a simple gameloop

```
//Game Loop
            boolean GameLoop = true;
            while(GameLoop){
            CG.refresh();
            }
```

and In main class I got something like this :

```
void refresh() {            
    Labels.MoneyLabel.setText("Money: " + CarMain.main[0]);
    Labels.BoxesLabel.setText("Boxes: " + CarMain.main[2]);
```

}

And It All worked. Now in Android I can't update my textviews.

On Android, onCreate method made simple game loop

```
     Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Collections();
                            SaveFile();
                            Refresh();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

and wanted to refresh textviews like

public void Refresh(){

```
 TextView MoneyTXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyText);
            MoneyTXT.setText("Money: " + Main.Money[0]);
            TextView  MoneyPerTapTXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MoneyPerTapTView);
            MoneyPerTapTXT.setText("$ " + Main.Money[1] + " per tap");
                TextView BoxesTXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesText);
                BoxesTXT.setText("Boxes: " + Main.Boxes[0]);
                TextView BoxesPerTapTXT = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.BoxesPerTapTView);
                BoxesPerTapTXT.setText("Points " + Main.Boxes[1] + " per tap");

}
```

But got error, becouse Textviews are located in different layouts.

Comment: 13 fragments? Are they all being shown at once? It seems like you're probably doing something incorrect if you're updating 13 fragments at once.

Comment: @nt-complete No, not at once, I just dont know how to refresh 1 of them. That are opened. I just want to know, how to acces them.

Comment: @nt-complete For simple example. Got Integer = Clicks. On button click I increment clicks +1; and textview need to be updated on click. I wanted to update textview on click, but can't becouse, click method are in mainActivity and textview in layout fragment

Answer (score 0):

To update a Fragment from an Activity:

Assuming your Fragment has been added to a view with the id `R.id.frame`, you would do:

```
// Get current Fragment   
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
if (fragment instanceof MyFragment) { //or whatever your Fragment's name is
    ((MyFragment) fragment).updateTextView(); // This is a method you will have to define yourself
}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to handle via method callback mechanism, you can try the event callback mechanism by using third party libraries like [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Simple example,

**Define events:**

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

**Prepare subscribers:(Subscribe your activity to receive events)** 
Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register and unregister your subscriber. For example on Android, activities and fragments should usually register according to their life cycle:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

**Post events:(On click of the fragment button post the event, activity will be notified immediately)**

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```